# $$typeof property requested by redux(?) and it's missing

Tags: javascript, redux, enums, typeof

I'm refactoring my redux code and I decided to replace strings serving as my action types with an enum. I created a class like this:

```
class Enum {
  constructor(enumObj) {

    const handler = {
      get: function(obj, prop) {
        if (prop in obj) {
          return obj[prop];
        }
        throw new Error(`${prop} is not a valid enum value for ${enumObj}`);
      }
    }
    return new Proxy(Object.freeze(enumObj), handler)
  }
}

export const ActionTypes = new Enum({
  SOME_ACTION: 'SOME_ACTION',
  ANOTHER_ACTION: 'ANOTHER_ACTION',
});
```

Unfortunately my app has started to crash with a message like

> Error: $$typeof is not a valid enum value for [object Object].

I'm definitely not requesting getting `$$typeof`. All I do with the `ActionTypes` enum is including that as part of my dispatched messages and then using it within switch-statement in my reducer.

I noticed that my app just works fine if I handle this case by adding a code to handler's `get` that returns `string` or `undefined` if `prop == '$$typeof'`. I could just leave it there, but I want to understand what's going on.

My question's are:

- what's `$$typeof`?
- what might be trying to access it and why?

Answer (score 1):

While this isn't a direct answer to your question, please note that [your action types *should* always be strings](https://redux.js.org/faq/actions#why-should-type-be-a-string-or-at-least-serializable-why-should-my-action-types-be-constants), and [you should *not*  put non-serializable values like class instances into your actions](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#do-not-put-non-serializable-values-in-state-or-actions).  I would strongly encourage you to switch back to using the previous approach.

As a related point, please look into using [our new official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux-toolkit.js.org), which includes utilities to simplify several common Redux use cases, including store setup, defining reducers, immutable update logic, and even creating entire "slices" of state at once.  In particular, if you use the [`createSlice` function](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice), it generates action types and action creators automatically so you don't have to write them by hand.

Comment: If I understand correctly, by using `ActionTypes.SOME_ACTION` in `dispatch` I'm really using a **string** that's just fetched in a fancy way. I'm not passing around Enum instances.